# Using Jasmine to test legacy global script files

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, legacy, jasmine-node

I have a brownfield application with a large number of infamously global javascript files. As an example, I have files like this that are loaded on the various html pages:

```
   var Class = {
    create: function() {
        return function () { this.initialize.apply(this, arguments); };
    }
};

var Dialog = Class.create();
Dialog.id = "dvDialogLayer";

function getPopupTop (){
 var win = window.top;
}
```

So I'd like to put these methods and objects under test as a first step to replacing them with a more modern pattern. I've installed Jasmine and Jasmine-Node and wrote a test like this, following the Jasmine style guide:

```
const Jasmine = require('jasmine');
const Subj = require('../../Scripts/dialog');//path to the dialog.js file

describe('Global Dialog script test', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
    });

    it('should create the Dialog class', () => {
        expect(Dialog).not.toBe(undefined);
    })

    it('should return the expected height for a dialog popup', () => {
        expect(getPopupTop().toBe(0));
    });
});
```

If I run the `jasmine` command, I get informed that the Dialog, Subjct, and getPopupTop are all undefined . I've been searching for the proper way to set this up, but haven't had any luck yet. Any idea what I could be doing wrong here and what the proper approach would be?

Comment: You need to export your class and functions to be able to access them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess. You're trying to use [CommonJS node modules](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules), whereas that JavaScript code is built for the browser and doesn't "export" anything. So you can't use "require".

You need to setup the module and exports properly.

It could be as simple as adding `module.exports = ...`, and you just export everything you need,
but legacy code is often wrapped in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) which could cause some extra difficulties with exporting.

Comment: Is this possible without modifying the legacy code and all the pages that call it? I don't mind modifying the legacy code file itself, but if we have to refactor the entire application to become testable I might have to give up on the idea

Comment: It should be possible by simply adding something like `exports = { Dialog, getPopupTop }` just take care that that code is written in a place where Dialog and getPopupTop are actually accessible (if Dialog is within an IIFE, that code also needs to be within the same IIFE). I am not 100% sure though. There are many moving parts here.

Comment: Another likely thing with this legacy code is that it has dependencies injected by <script> tags. In that case you will need to figure out a way to provide those dependencies in the node environment as well.

Comment: I guess I'm attempting to use node.js modules since I'm using node to run jasmine. I tried adding `exports = { Dialog, getPopupTop }` but the Subjct object is complete empty and doesn't contain either Dialog or the getPopupTop function. Is there something I need to update in my require statement?

Comment: Was able to follow your advice combined with NodeJs documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) and came up with this:
`exports.ACADialog = ACADialog;
exports.getPopupTop = getPopupTop;`

That got everything exported properly for the require. If you cant to update the code bit of your answer I'd be happy to accept this as the answer